# inner join in r gives much more rows than either data frame

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I have two dataframes with tonnes of data
both having around 10 Million rows

when I use this query in r:

```
df<-inner_join(frame1,frame2,by=c("id1"="id2"))
```

This returns df which has 90 Million rows. I don't understand how is that possible and how could I potentially avoid this.

Comment: Are the id's truly unique? If not your inner join will be closer to a cross join which heavily increases the amount of rows

Comment: It acts that way because that's how join acts, your expectations are wrong, say what you think it should return & why with justification referencing authoritative documentation. Don't ask us to write yet another presentation with no idea what your misconceptions are. [mre]

Comment: [I agree this seems to be based on having a mistaken expectation, but it seems likely to me it's based on a very understandable misunderstanding -- "inner_join is depicted as the inner part of the venn diagram, how could it be bigger than either part?" If this is a duplicate with a better reference elsewhere, I agree with closing, but otherwise this seems like a useful question to have answered somewhere.]

Answer (score 3):

To give an example of @Wietse de Vries's comment, suppose we inner join this table to itself:

```
frame1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,2,3,3,3), row = 1:6)
inner_join(frame1, frame1, by = c("id1" = "id1"))

#   id1 row.x row.y
#1    1     1     1
#2    2     2     2
#3    2     2     3
#4    2     3     2
#5    2     3     3
#6    3     4     4
#7    3     4     5
#8    3     4     6
#9    3     5     4
#10   3     5     5
#11   3     5     6
#12   3     6     4
#13   3     6     5
#14   3     6     6
```

The output increases with the square of the number of appearances of each key value -- ie 1 row for id1, 4 for id2, 9 for id3, etc. You could get to 90 million rows if there are a large number of mutual matches between the tables.

To avoid this, make the lists of keys distinct, with only one of each:

```
frame1_distinct <- frame1 %>% distinct(id1, .keep_all = TRUE)
inner_join(frame1_distinct, frame1_distinct, by = c("id1" = "id1"))

  id1 row.x row.y
1   1     1     1
2   2     2     2
3   3     4     4
```